# Tmux send-keys using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, tmux, sendkeys

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=$1
while read line; do
 $line
done < myfile.txt
```

This code is supposed to read line by line from a text file and then execute a tmux send-keys line

The problem is the keys send, but there is no space between the input that is sent to tmux.

So if I try to send

```
tmux send keys -t MySession 'Foo Bar'
```

The output appears as FooBar in the tmux session

Comment: Why are you not executing the script itself, as `/bin/sh myfile.txt` ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, would that make a difference?  I'm new to shell/bash

Comment: When you give a filename argument to the shell, it reads each line and executes it. That's how scripts work.

Comment: It makes no difference, I'm inclided to think this is a glitch using tmux

Comment: What is the `FILE` variable for?

Comment: Also, I was amused, you've one wrapper shell script, which you executed directly & one shell script, which you are trying to execute with an explicit loop... :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `eval` to execute the command, because quotes aren't processed when expanding a variable. So it should be:

```
eval "$line"
```

But your whole loop is pretty much equivalent to doing

```
/bin/sh < myfile.txt
```

because the shell does the same thing your script does: read each line and execute it.

Comment: Also @OP: `eval '$line"` may still not work, if the command does not end by newline. e.g. `if ....; then`<newline>`commands`<newline>`fi`. Here, for using the explicit loop logic, entire if to fi needs to be on the same line in myfile.txt.

Comment: That's true, but I expect that his file is not really a complex script, but just a series of one-liners.